# C#: Error when updating a web service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am getting this error message in the web service when i am updating the reference

Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've used a control or component in the web-service interface (i.e. as a return value or method argument). That won't work - as it needs to serialize (typically) as xml. You would typically send *data* in objects - not controls.

What does the service interface look like?